# Not able to store media title using python feedparser

Tags: python, rss, media, rss-reader, feedparser

I a trying to store feeds from a website using feedparser, but the problem is in xml format each media-content has a media -title in it but while parsing using python feedparser library i can't get the media-title.

```
<media:thumbnail url="https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/oscarlead.jpg?quality=85&amp;strip=info&amp;w=500" />
        <media:content url="http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/b51c0c859ad69354d498cd688e281907?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F2.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&amp;r=X" medium="image">
        <media:category>author</media:category>
    </media:content>
        <media:content url="https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-2.gif" medium="image">
        <media:title>nicoleslenderman</media:title>
                </media:content>
        <media:content url="https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-29.jpg?quality=85&amp;strip=info" medium="image">
        <media:title>oscar-tweet9</media:title>
                </media:content>
        <media:content url="https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-28.jpg?quality=85&amp;strip=info" medium="image">
        <media:title>oscar-tweet8</media:title>
                </media:content>
        <media:content url="https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-27.jpg?quality=85&amp;strip=info" medium="image">
        <media:title>oscar-tweet7</media:title>
                </media:content>
        <media:content url="https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-26.jpg?quality=85&amp;strip=info" medium="image">
        <media:title>oscar-tweet6</media:title>
                </media:content>
        <media:content url="https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-25.jpg?quality=85&amp;strip=info" medium="image">
        <media:title>oscar-tweet5</media:title>
                </media:content>
        <media:content url="https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-21.gif" medium="image">
        <media:title>oscarshighfive</media:title>
                </media:content>
        <media:content url="https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-24.jpg?quality=85&amp;strip=info" medium="image">
        <media:title>oscar-tweet4</media:title>
                </media:content>
        <media:content url="https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-23.jpg?quality=85&amp;strip=info" medium="image">
        <media:title>oscar-tweet3</media:title>
                </media:content>
        <media:content url="https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/stealoscar.gif" medium="image">
        <media:title>stealoscar</media:title>
                </media:content>
        <media:content url="https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-22.jpg?quality=85&amp;strip=info" medium="image">
        <media:title>oscar-tweet2</media:title>
                </media:content>
        <media:content url="https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-21.jpg?quality=85&amp;strip=info" medium="image">
        <media:title>oscar-tweet1</media:title>
                </media:content>
        <media:content url="https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-2.jpg?quality=85&amp;strip=info" medium="image">
        <media:title>oscar-tweet0</media:title>
                </media:content>
        <media:content url="https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/oscargif.gif" medium="image">
        <media:title>oscargif</media:title>
                </media:content>
```

But when i parse using feedparser i don't get media title. I only get following details

```
'media_content': [{'url': u'http://2.gravatar.com/avatar/b51c0c859ad69354d498cd688e281907?s=50&d=http%3A%2F%2F2.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D50&r=X', 'medium': u'image'},
 {'url': u'https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-2.gif', 'medium': u'image'},                           
 {'url': u'https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-29.jpg?quality=85&strip=info', 'medium': u'image'},                             {'url': u'https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-28.jpg?quality=85&strip=info', 'medium': u'image'},     {'url': u'https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-27.jpg?quality=85&strip=info', 'medium': u'image'}, {'url': u'https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-26.jpg?quality=85&strip=info', 'medium': u'image'}, {'url': u'https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-25.jpg?quality=85&strip=info', 'medium': u'image'}, {'url': u'https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-21.gif', 'medium': u'image'}, {'url': u'https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-24.jpg?quality=85&strip=info', 'medium': u'image'}, {'url': u'https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-23.jpg?quality=85&strip=info', 'medium': u'image'}, {'url': u'https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/stealoscar.gif', 'medium': u'image'}, {'url': u'https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-22.jpg?quality=85&strip=info', 'medium': u'image'}, {'url': u'https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-21.jpg?quality=85&strip=info', 'medium': u'image'}, {'url': u'https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/best-oscar-tweets-so-far-x-photos-2.jpg?quality=85&strip=info', 'medium': u'image'}, {'url': u'https://thechive.files.wordpress.com/2017/02/oscargif.gif', 'medium': u'image'}]
```

So in this a list of dictionary i only get two attributes url and medium. So how to fetch title.

and here is my code :-

```
    d = feedparser.parse(url_dict[item])
    total_entries = len(d.entries)

    try:
        for entry in range(0, total_entries):
            data = d.entries[entry]

            print (data)
            article_date = data.get('published', '')
            article_title = data.get('title', '')
            content = data.get('content', '')
            summary = data.get('summary', '')
            media_content = data.get('media_content')
            print media_content
```

Comment: It is better to provide your question with some codes you have written, so that other persons are able to investigate the possible fault.

Comment: @Hossein  i have added the code.

Comment: So far, best as I can tell, this is a bug in feedparser. I'm having the same issue. https://github.com/libo26/feedparser/issues/257